# Copying files from multiple directories to a single

Tags: linux, data-management

I have multiple .GFF files, each in a single directory per annotated whole genome, that I wish to copy into a single directory so that I can perform a core genome alignment.

However the following code does not seem to work:

```
for pathname in "~/ST_0075/annotations/*/*.gff"; do cp "$pathname" ~/ST_0075/alignment; done
```

The directory structure is the following:

```
Home
-ST_0075
---Annotations
-----Sample_001
----------001.gff
```

The goal is to copy from multiple Sample_XXX subdirectories within `Annotations` the XXX.gff files into another directory named `alignment`

Answer (score 3):

Tinkered a bit and realized the solution did not neccistate a for loop.

```
mkdir ~/ST_0075/alignment; cp ~/ST_0075/annotations/*/*.gff ~/ST_0075/alignment
```

Comment: Exactly, and thanks for posting an answer! Note that if you're using bash, you can make it even simpler if you enable `globstar`. You can do: `shopt -s globstar; cp ~/ST_0075/annotations/**/*.gff ~/ST_0075/alignment` and that will recurse an arbitrary number of directories under `annotations`, so you don't need to count the exact number of `*/` you need.

Comment: Hi @terdon, is it `**` that is doing the trick?

Comment: Yes, try `man bash | grep -A3 'globstar$'` to see the details.